# Compute the intersection of a cube with a plane in Three.js

Tags: typescript, three.js, 3d, intersection, plane

Given a plane and a cube, I'd like to know whether they intersect. If they do, I'd also like to know:

1. do their intersection form a triangle, a parallelogram or an hexagon

   - or a point, or a segment in the degenerated cases
2. what are the coordinates of the vertices of the intersection

   2.1. in the standard frame of reference

   2.2. in the cube's frame of reference

Note:

- The cube is a `new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1)` which has undergone translation and rotation through `applyMatrix4` of a translation and rotation matrix
- The plane is an arbitrary `new THREE.Plane()`

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the Three.js documentation, I found the following:

- `Plane` has a method [`intersectBox`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=Box#api/en/math/Plane.intersectsBox) which tells whether or not the plane intersect with a given `Box3`.
- More importantly, `Plane` has a method [`intersectLine`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=Box#api/en/math/Plane.intersectLine) which tells *where* a given Line3 intersect the plane.
- Three.js examples include a class [`ConvexHull`](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/math/convexhull/ConvexHull) which builds a convex polyhedron from a set of vertices:

```
new ConvexHull().setFromPoints(points).faces
```

So a possible approach to the problem would be to:

1. Break down the cube into 12 lines, one for each edge,
2. check each line for intersection against the plane. If the line intersect, add the intersection point to the convex hull

---

I ended up not using the convex hull approach. I just create all the possible faces thanks to a triple nested loop over the intersection points.